# Enforce style of named list items in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, data-validation

I have a named list with some values which have their own style (e.g. different colors):

[image]

However when I apply that list as a `data validation` and select some values, the styling disappears:

[image]:

**How can I get the style of the named list values to be applied when re-used in a data validation list?**

Answer (score 1):

The most lightweight way to solve this problem is to set up 4 different conditional formatting rules for the cell with the dropdown.  Each rule would be something very simple, like `=B2="+"` applied to `B2`.